# C#: How to execute thread without halting program execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am making a memory game. Whenever user clicks on a button, an image is revealed. Then user has to click on another button. If both images match, then buttons are replaced by a tick mark. If not, then there is a 1 sec gap for the user to memorize the image location..and then again, images are hidden and buttons are shown.
I do the 1 sec gap by
      Thread.Sleep(1000)

I have embedded a countdown timer in the game whose duration is 30 sec. I have placed a label which shows the 30 second countdown on each clock tick.

---

Now the actual problem is, that whenever Thread.Sleep(1000) is invoked, the timer halts. And after 1 sec, it resumes. I want this timer to execute regardless of Thread. Please help.

Comment: The solution is to *not block the UI thread* rather than to block the UI thread and have the UI still be responsive.

Comment: Why are you calling Thread.Sleep(1000) in the first place if you have a timer?  Please post some code for us to look into.

Comment: because the The timer is on the same thread as where you are executing it from, which also is where Thread.Sleep lives - this is the problem. you need to separate the 2....you are blocking your main (UI in this case) thread when you are doing Thread.Sleep. Show code you are currently using!

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep != System.Threading.Timer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand exactly what you are asking, so apologies if I've misunderstood you, but I think you are asking how you can update the UI using a timer on a new thread without blocking the UI thread? The answer is that you cannot update a UI control in a thread other than the one that it was created in. Instead you have to create a delegate to do it for you.

So, this gives you an exception because the callback `UpdateText` at the end of the timer executes on the timer thread, not the main UI thread:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateText, null, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}

public void UpdateText(object state)
{
    this.textBox1.AppendText("Ouch!" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Whereas, this works as expected: When you click the button, one second later the word "Ouch!" appears in the text box. This is because the use of the `BeginInvoke` method on the textbox control with the `MethodInvoker` delegate causes the delegate to execute on the thread that owns the control (i.e. the main UI thread) rather than on the timer thread:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateText, null, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}

public void UpdateText(object state)
{
    MethodInvoker action = delegate
    {
        this.textBox1.AppendText("Ouch!" + Environment.NewLine);
    };

    this.textBox1.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```